# Extracting the inside of an expression using REGEX

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I currently have this regular expression that I use to match the result of an SQL query: `[^\\n]+(?=\\r\\n\\r\\n\(1 rows affected\))`. However, it is not working as intended....

```
'\r\n----------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------\r\nCS: GPS
on Date.

                                                      \r\n\r\n(1 rows affected)\r\n'
```

What I get from the expression above is `Date` whereas I would want to match `CS: GPS on Date.` It's fine if there's leading and following spaces... Nothing Python's trim can't handle. How do I change my regular expression so that the match is done properly?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: The Python version I am using is Python 3.6

Comment: I added python to your tags, but it would be best to specify the version you're using.

Comment: Are `\n` and `\r` actually textual or are they realistically newline characters in the output you're receiving (does your output actually output newlines or the literal substring `\n`)? Also, is your positive lookahead static, or is there sometimes more `\r\n` in the result?

Comment: @ctwheels anything inside the single commas is plain-text

Comment: Does `((?:(?!\\n|(?<=\\)n)[\s\S])+?)\s*\\r\\n\\r\\n\(1 rows affected\)` work for you? See it in use [here](https://regex101.com/r/jbhFmY/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get your current match because the character class `[^\\n]+` matches 1+ times any char except `\` or `n`.

Then the positive lookahead asserts what is on the right is `\r\n\r\n(1 rows affected)` which results in matching  `Date.`

See https://regex101.com/r/wDzq8l/1

You could use a non greedy `.+?` in a capturing group and match what follows instead of using a positive lookahead.

In the code use `re.DOTALL` to let the dot match a newline.

```
-\\r\\n(.+?) ?\\r\\n\\r\\n\(\d+ rows affected\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2yS5F8/1)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, some expression similar to:

```
-{5,}\s*([A-Za-z][^.]+\.)
```

would extract that or somewhat similar to that.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8yfjnF/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r'-{5,}\s*([A-Za-z][^.]+\.)'
string = '''

----------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
CS: GPS
on Date.

                                                      \r\n\r\n(1 rows affected)\r\n
'''

print(re.findall(regex, string, re.DOTALL))
```

#### Output

```
['CS: GPS\non Date.']
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/8yfjnF/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/8yfjnF/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: The input string does not match my output string, I think you missed the \r\n after the dashline, but that looks pretty interesting. I'll have a closer look of your expression and I'll see if I can find something that matches what I need. Thank you!